# Sync Core Data Between iPhone and iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, networking

I have an iPhone app and I want to make it universal so it works on the iPad.

Is there an easy way to setup sync between the iPhone and iPad? I'm absolutely a noob when it comes to URL and HTML requests and json etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple recently announced iCloud, but we cannot discuss the development details here since it is under NDA.  If you are an Apple Developer, I would recommend reading some of the details in the Apple Forums about this topic.